# How to click the JavaScript Element in Selenium WebDriver using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

i want to click the headerAssetName javajscript element using seleinum web driver in ruby

```
<th class="headerIconURL" scope="col">
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$cphMainContent$gvAssets&#39;,&#39;Sort$IconID&#39;)">Type</a>
</th>
```

i tried the find element with css method and its not working

```
'@driver.find_element(:css,'th.headerIconURL').click'
```

could you please anyone help to click the element using selenium web driver?
do i need to do anything special on java href element?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that the CSS-selector clicks the th element. Click events typically only bubble upwards. This means that the link, which is lower in the DOM, never realizes it should be clicked and trigger the javascript.

Try clicking the link instead:

```
@driver.find_element(:css,'th.headerIconURL' a).click
```